# Font size should decrease once it's length greater than 15

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="textLength" class="textLength"> Hello World !!!</div>
<script>
function testTextLength() {
    var textL = document.getElementById("textLength").innerText;
    var maxLength = 15;
    if (textL.length > maxLength) {
        textL.style.fontSize = "250%";
    }
}
</script>
```

Please help me that font size of "Hello World !!!" should change after reaching the more than 15 characters.

Comment: So when are you calling it? How is the text editing? When is it called?

Comment: you're going to need to bind a change event to your div element, and probably change your div to an input

Comment: Yes i want like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the fontsize to the innertext. Set it to the element.

```
<div id="textLength" class="textLength"> Hello World !!!</div>
<script>
function testTextLength() {
    var textL = document.getElementById("textLength");
    var maxLength = 15;
    if (textL.innerText.length > maxLength) {
        textL.style.fontSize = "250%";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: if you see the code in the question its like document.getElementById("textLength").innerText.style.fontSize = "250%";

Comment: in my case its document.getElementById("textLength").style.fontSi‌​ze = "250%";

Comment: A great Thank you for you8r Great Help

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do. Change your div to an input:

```
<input id="textLength" class="textLength">
```

Then, bind an event to it, like 'keyup'. You need this so your JS knows when to check on the length of text entered.

```
<script>
     var textL = document.getElementById("textLength");

     textL.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
         var maxLength = 15;
         var txt = textL.value;
         if (txt.length > maxLength) textL.style.fontSize = "250%";
     });
</script>
```

Instead of 'keyup', you could also listen for 'keypress', 'keydown' or 'change'. In this case, I recommend using 'keyup'. Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/wxmvagL3/3/

If you want to reset the font size when the length goes below 15 chars, add an else block:

```
if (txt.length > maxLength) textL.style.fontSize = "250%";
else textL.style.fontSize = "100%";
```